# CouchDB Futon custom URL

Tags: dns, ip, couchdb, settings, couchdb-futon

I just installed CouchDB on my Ubuntu 12.04 server and I am trying to find a way to access Futon (the web based admin panel) using the IP of my computer or one of the domains I have binded on it.

I have added the following below the `[httpd]` section in `/etc/couchdb/local.ini`

```
port = 5984
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

But navigating to my_ip:5984 has no results. I restarted the CouchDB server several times though.

Could you please help me out with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open port 5984 in firewall. And then:
IP:5984/_utils/